# How do I add a custom font in React Native?

Tags: react-native, fonts

I'm running this on ios. I followed the steps [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/using-custom-fonts-in-react-native-2019-289099609837) and was able to get the "Montserrat-SemiBold" font to work. I tried doing the same thing with "Source Sans Pro" but I'm getting the error "Unrecognized font family".

I've spent a couple of hours trying multiple things I found online but can't get it to work.

This is my repo => [RefugeApp](https://github.com/Jeff-Enriquez/RefugeApp)

p.s. I'm using VSCode

Answer (score 2):

1 - download all the fonts you want (make sure its terminated in **.ttf** example: Arial-narrow.ttf)

2 - rename it as simple as possible eg: from **piazzolla-reagular=s8.ttf** to **piazzolla-regular.ttf**

3 - create an "**assets**" folder on your project (you probably already have created one)

4 - create a folder named "**fonts**" inside your your assets folder and paste all your downloaded (and renamed) fonts inside there

5 - create a file named "**react-native.config.js**" inside your project **and fill the inside** with this code:

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {}, // grouped into "project"
  },
  assets: ["./assets/fonts/"], // stays the same
};
```

6 - **on your console** (inside your project directory) write:

```
npx react-native link
```

this will link your project...

now, to apply your fonts on your  style component use the **fontFamily** prop, eg:

```
style={{color:'#999',fontFamily:'exo2-regular'}}
```

hope this helps everyone whos in need of a font guide.
ps: I concat this method from various website guides around web like:
https://mehrankhandev.medium.com/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4
[How do I add a custom font in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63714649/how-do-i-add-a-custom-font-in-react-native)
https://medium.com/@alcides.bsilvaneto/installing-custom-fonts-ttf-or-otf-on-react-native-0-60-projects-e8dafbc0dff3
No credits for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use expo-font to use custom fonts, It's easy and straight forward.

Steps to use custom fonts with expo-font on the bare react-native project.

1. [Install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-unimodules) and config unimodules on iOS/Android

   - [Configuration for iOS](https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/#configuration-for-ios)
   - [Configuration for Android](https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/#configuration-for-android)
2. Install `expo-font`

   - `npm i expo-font`
3. Setup your custom fonts on your App.js

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import * as Font from "expo-font";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    appIsReady: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.prepareResources();
  }

  prepareResources = async () => {
    await cacheAssets();

    this.setState({ appIsReady: true });
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.appIsReady) {
      return <Text>loading...</Text>;
    }

    return <Text>App</Text>;
  }
}

async function cacheAssets() {
  const fontAssets = cacheFonts([
    { thin: require("./assets/fonts/thin.ttf") },
    { medium: require("./assets/fonts/medium.ttf") },
    { bold: require("./assets/fonts/bold.ttf") },
  ]);

  await Promise.all([...fontAssets]);
}

function cacheFonts(fonts) {
  return fonts.map((font) => Font.loadAsync(font));
}

export default App;
```

4. Use it

```
<Text style={{ fontFamily: "medium" }}>App</Text>
```

This might be helpful if anyone using react-native-unimodules and wants to config custom fonts.

Answer (score 0):

- If you were able to do it correctly for `Montserrat-SemiBold` I suppose that your fonts are installed correct so I will skip this step, let's go to **"Unrecognized font family"** problem
- You need to check font name in your system, not by name of the file, you need to open [font_book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XydI6.png) in `Launchpad` and check font that you interested in [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCO1s.png)
- For example the name of file `IMFellEnglishSC-Regular.ttf` but in the system, it could be `IM_FELL_English_SC` with underscores `_` :)
- So you need to use it like `fontFamily: IM_FELL_English_SC`, even if filename is different
- In your case seems like `fontFamily: SourceSansPro-Regular` should work for you check this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABqZT.png)
- For future you could use this cool package to easy link & unlink fonts it's quite cool and simple for such things like adding custom fonts -> [react-native-assets](https://github.com/unimonkiez/react-native-asset)
- Cheers ‍♂️☀️